# Data lost after insert to PostgreSQL Data base

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

I build pretty easy etl procces that get data from one DB and put it to another one.

```
eng1=sqlalchemy.create_engine(url1)  
eng2=sqlalchemy.create_engine(url2) 
for df in pd.read_sql(query,eng,chuncksize=1000):  
    df.to_sql(table_name,eng2, if_exists='append')
```

During it I catch two mysterious fails.

*First* is that some data is **lost**. It hasn't reached destination table.
*Second* is that all the data that's reached the destination **is being expired** in a few moments.

My colleague tried to build dummy ETL with **another** table and it works pretty nice.  But the destination table couldn't be changed and it's kinda interesting what's wrong with the table or process.

Comment: Did you forget to commit the inserting transaction?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sure I did!

Comment: We try to upload the same data with the same process to another table and everything went good. The problem is with this mystery table

Comment: Log SQL statements in PostgreSQL and see what actually happens.